# Symfony 2 File Upload. How to throw exception on move()

Tags: file-upload, symfony

Reading the symfony docs, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

```
// you must throw an exception here if the file cannot be moved
// so that the entity is not persisted to the database
// which the UploadedFile move() method does automatically
$this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);
```

But if I did

```
if ($this->file->move(...))
```

I got an error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File could not be converted to boolean in .../xxx.php line 96

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the source code : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php#L108

It seems that an exception is already thrown.

Cheers

Comment: Documentation updated - https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/908

The system works!